# Install ROS on Arch Linux on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, archlinux, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone successfully installed ROS Arch Linux on Raspberry Pi? I saw @MarkyMark2012 got ROS going on Debian and RPi [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/34501/how-to-setting-up-ros-on-raspberrypi/).

I tried following the Arch Linux [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Arch) but they don't work. There appears to be no tool called "packer" either installed by default or found using pacman (their package installer). Also the work around for python didn't work at all for me ... I just got lots of errors.

Before I waste a lot of time figuring out my issues with python ... just wondering if anyone has already solved this and documented it somewhere? Or is there an SD Card image available I could just download?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45246/install-ros-on-arch-linux-on-raspberry-pi/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I gave up on ROS on Arch Linux because of the Python 3 issues. I ran into too many issues getting ROS to work with what it likes (python 2) and what Arch likes (python 3).

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, I never tried that. But I think building at lest the core ROS components shoudl work.

You can get packer from the [AUR database](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=33378).

The python issue is a little tricky. The first approach that is mentioned on the wiki page is to change the link /usr/bin/python to point to python2. You shouldn't do that because there is the great risk that you break half of the system by doing that. The second approach, i.e. replacing all #! python lines to explicitly call python2 can be quite tedious because you might still need manual fixes. However, rosinstall/rosws should work with python3 already. I suggest to install them using pip or pip2 if you want to use python2. If you can edit your original post and add some of the error messages you get, I might be able to help.

I wrapped a few ROS Electric packages into AUR files and I'm still working on getting clean packages for Fuerte. You can find what I have so far on [github](https://github.com/moesenle/arch-ros-stacks).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3